# Making a cross-thread call to a ListView

Tags: c#, listview, multithreading, delegates

I have a thread running in the background that periodically tries to update a ListView component, but every time it attempts to I get a "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'dlList' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on." error. I have used a delegate to try and solve this but it isn't fixing the problem. Is there something wrong with my code? I've also tried Invoke instead of BeginInvoke but same issue.

```
    delegate void updateListItemDelegate(string tag, ListViewItem lv);
    private void updateListItem(string tag, ListViewItem lv)
    {
        if (this.dlList.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.dlList.BeginInvoke(new updateListItemDelegate(updateListItem),tag,lv);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            int index = -1;
            foreach (ListViewItem x in dlList.Items)
            {
                if (x.Tag.ToString() == tag)
                    index = x.Index;
            }
            if (index != -1)
            {
                dlList.Items[index].SubItems[1] = lv.SubItems[1];
                dlList.Items[index].SubItems[3] = lv.SubItems[3];
            }
        }
    }
```

Called via:

```
    updateListItem(x.url, x.details);
```

Comment: Exactly where is the exception thrown? Can you share the call stack from the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Try the AsyncObservableCollection from [Thomas Levesque](http://tomlev2.wordpress.com/2009/04/17/wpf-binding-to-an-asynchronous-collection/).

Answer (score 0):

Ah. I had a try {} catch {} around the code logging the exception, didn't realise that a ListView item I had set in a class also required a delegate to make a call to it as well as the form component. Nice tip Fredrik!